# how can I make one button correspond to different clicked div html jquery php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

You can see my code below. I face a challenge that I don't know how to use one button to correspond different click. On the php, if I put the button inside the foreach loop, it will create a lot of button, that's not what I want. In the js, if I put the on.click button inside the foreach elements loop, it will also create a lot of on.click button, so I click one button, it will run many times depends on the number of label_name. I think about addClass, if I clicked the heart div, I use js to add a class, and then get the attr('id') inside button.on.(click), so I can differentiate them in my server php and mysql can request the correspond data. But the problem is that if a user click every div, then every div add classes, then problem again.

```js
var current_page = 1;

var elements_body = {
    "heart": "1",
    "eye": "2",
    "ear_nose_throat": "3",
    "hand_foot_mouth": "4"
};
jQuery.each(elements_body, function (label_name, label_num) {
    var disease_label = $('#' + label_name + '_d');

    disease_label.on('click', function () {

        var data = {
            action: 'body_part_keyword', //wordpress loading url
            postSearchNonce: MyAjaxSearch.postSearchNonce,
            current_page: current_page,
            label_name: label_name //this label_name will differentiate data that need to request from mysql in the action.php 
        };
        $.ajax({
            url: MyAjaxSearch.ajaxurl,
            type: 'POST',
            cache: false,
            data: data,
            success: function (data) {

                disease_menu_result.append(data);
                current_page++

            }
        }); //ajax
    });

}); //jQuery.each

$('#loadmorebutton_body').on('click', function () {
    //I dont know how can I make this button to correspond above code

});
```

```html
<div id="disease_menu">

    <?php
        $arr = Array(
            'heart'=>'heart',
            'eye'=>'eye',
            'ear_nose_throat'=>'ear nose throat',
            'hand_foot_mouth'=>'hand foot mouth'
        );

        foreach ($arr as $key=>$value) {
    ?>
    <div class="disease_li" id="disease_li_<?php echo $key;?>">
        <span class="disease_span" id="<?php echo $key;?>_d"><label>(<?php echo $value;?>)</label>diseases</span>
    </div>
    <!--disease_li-->

    <?php }?>
</div>
<!--disease_menu-->

<button id="loadmorebutton_body">Load More</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript functions :

```
function MyFunction() {
    jQuery.each( elements_body, function( label_name, label_num) {
        var disease_label= $('#'+ label_name + '_d'); 
        disease_label.on('click',function(){         
        var data={ 
                        action: 'body_part_keyword',//wordpress loading url
                    postSearchNonce : MyAjaxSearch.postSearchNonce,
                      current_page:current_page,
                     label_name:label_name//this label_name will differentiate data that need to request from mysql in the action.php 
               };
        $.ajax({
            url: MyAjaxSearch.ajaxurl,
            type:'POST',
            cache: false,
            data: data,
         success: function(data){

                          disease_menu_result.append(data);
                          current_page++

            }
                });//ajax
      });

      });
}
 $('#loadmorebutton_body').on('click',function(){
     MyFunction();
 }
```

Comment: it run a lot of times.